# Arangodb version 2.7.0.: error 1203 when querying with NEIGHBORS

Tags: arangodb

Having this small dataset in ArangoDB version 2.7.0:

```
db._useDatabase("Test"); 
db._create("authors");
var john = db.authors.save({ name: { first: "John", last: "Doe" }, _key: "doe" })._id;
var frau = db.authors.save({ name: { first: "Maxima", last: "Musterfrau" }, _key: "frau" })._id;
db._create("books");
var b1 = db.books.save({ title: "The beauty of JOINS", _key: "joins" })._id;
var b2 = db.books.save({ title: "The 2nd beauty of JOINS", _key: "joinsa" })._id;
db._createEdgeCollection("written");
db.written.save(john, b1, { year: 2003 });
db.written.save(frau, b2, { year: 2001 });
```

The when querying with:

```
FOR b IN books 
RETURN { book: b, authors: NEIGHBORS(authors, written, b._id, 'any', [], {includeData: true}) }
```

I get error:

> [1203] collection not found (while executing)

In version 2.6.9 this works fine. Has something changed in the NEIGHBORS syntax or can someone verify this behaviour?

Thanks in advance
Soren

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Referencing the NEIGHBOURS Documentation](https://docs.arangodb.com/Aql/GraphFunctions.html), the `startvertex` `b._id` is looked up in the `vertexcollection`. 
However, `b._id` belongs to `books` so you can't make it look it up in `authors` - you would need to specify `books` instead.

Actually there was a bug in 2.6.9 which would do that wrong. (Will also be fixed in 2.6.10)

And yes, regarding the error message there is definitely room for improvement - stay tuned..

Comment: Excellent. Nice to get that cleaned up. The wrong usage wasn't even intuitive to me.

Comment: error message fixed in https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/commit/04b1d75d517287a868f99531d3da52fc6643c21e; will be part of 2.7.2